# ruby/rails how to insert column into multidimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array

I have an array `arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]` and a column `col = [5,6]`

Is there an easy way to get an output of `[[1,2,5],[3,4,6]]` without looping? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using `Array#transpose` as follows:

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]
col = [5,6]
pp (arr.transpose << col).transpose # => [[1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: @mechanicalfish Just wanted to let you know the comment you responded to was deleted in case you wanted to delete yours. :-)

Comment: What about inserting the new column in to the first index?